# Angular routing problem - routing won't work as usual

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem where when I type manually localhost:4200/create it goes on the page where i want it to go, but when I click on a link to lead me there, I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
    at PostListComponent.ngOnDestroy
```

Here's my code:

header.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span><a routerLink="/">My Messages</a></span>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/create">New Post</a></li>
  </ul>
</mat-toolbar>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: PostListComponent},
  {path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

postlistcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { Post } from '../posts';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  posts: Post[] = [];
  private postsSub: Subscription;
  constructor(public postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsService.getPosts();
    this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }

  onDelete(postId: string) {
    this.postsService.deletePost(postId);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.postsSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your router-outlet

Comment: its in app.component.html

Comment: Show `PostListComponent.ts`

Comment: there, i edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says, you're calling `unsubscribe` on an object that doesn't exist in `PostListComponent` (postlist.component.ts?)

In that file, find the `ngOnDestroy` function and for any `this.object$.unsubscribe()` functions, test for the object first -

```
if (this.object$ && !this.object$.closed) {
   this.object$.unsubscribe()
}
```

I'm using `this.object$` as an example - your variable will be called something different

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from `/` to `/create` your `ngOnDestroy` in the `PostListComponent` is throwing an error.

This is why it is happening on the link and not when you put in the url.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your ngInit you are not passing any value to your variable (postsSub). That is why you cannot destroy it.

Change this :

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsService.getPosts();
    this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
```

For this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsService.getPosts();
    this.postsSub = this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });
  }
```

That should work.

Regards

Comment: Thank you my friend, but the problem is solved. Cheers!